# Redux Persist exclude one field(reducer) from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

How can I exclude "accessToken" field from "auth" reducer, using redux-persist? I tried to blacklist "auth" reducer and it works, but I need only one field

State:
https://monosnap.com/file/RhschoXwMAyL1cd3r67ywIA4lHM2bt

```
Persist config:
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  blacklist: ['auth'],
  storage: AsyncStorage
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, getMiddlewares);

export default store;

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Write a blacklist at the reducer level

Go to your reducer list and when returning the reducer for auth you need to return the persist config for that particular reducer.

You're currently black listing the entire reducer instead of just one part.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late. But may be this can help others.
You can whitelist or blacklist fields using **redux-persist-transform-filter** library.
Example to exclude `field1` and `field2` from `myReducer`:

```
import { createBlacklistFilter } from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const saveSubsetBlacklistFilter = createBlacklistFilter('myReducer', ['field1', 'field2']);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  myReducer: authReducer,
  //your other reducers ...
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  transforms: [saveSubsetBlacklistFilter]
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```